# Convert dd days hh:mm:ss to second in Python

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

For a `diff` column in dataframe which get by:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df['diff'] = df['start'] - df['end']

0    0 days 00:06:15
1    0 days 00:05:10
2    1 days 00:05:50
3    0 days 00:06:20
4    0 days 00:05:37
5    0 days 00:04:48
```

How could I convert `diff` column to `seconds` (ie, first rows is `6 * 60 + 15 = 375`)? Thanks.

Comment: You just did; what do you need help with?

Comment: `df['diff'].dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: Sorry for the late of my reply, yes, your code works. @cs95